# Questions about orthogonal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$ be vectors in $V$ with dimension $n$. Suppose that the lengths of $a_1, b_1$ are the same and the lengths of $a_2, b_2$ are the same. Suppose that the angle of $a_1, a_2$ is the same as the angle of $b_1, b_2$. How to show that there is an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $Aa_1 = b_1, Aa_2=b_2$? I think that the inner product of $a_1, a_2$ is the same as the inner product of $b_1, b_2$. But I don't know how to construct $A$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to show this:

1) Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to find orthonormal bases of the spaces spanned by $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2\}$.  Since the inner product of $a_1$ with $a_2$ is the same as the inner product of $b_1$ with $b_2$, when you write $a_i$ in terms of the orthonormal basis of the space spanned by $\{a_1,a_2\}$, the coefficients will be same as when you write $b_i$ in terms of the orthonormal basis of the space spanned by $\{b_1,b_2\}$ (for $i=1,2$).

2) Complete your orthonormal sets to orthonormal bases of $V$.

3) There is an orthogonal matrix $A$ that takes the first basis to the second (one characterization of an orthogonal matrix is that it takes an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis).

4) Because of the properties mentioned in part 1), this matrix $A$ takes $a_1$ to $b_1$ and $a_2$ to $b_2$.